# ExpressVPN: Apps in split tunnel can't access Localhost

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

ExpressVPN has a useful Split Tunneling feature: certain apps can be excluded from the VPN. However such apps are no longer able to access Localhost. Any way to fix this?

I'm on windows 10. Would a custom firewall rule do it perhaps? I'm not exactly sure how expressvpn controls which packets go to the vpn or not.

P.S. I have turned on the setting [Internet Lock -> Allow Access To Devices On The Local Network]

P.S.S. ExpressVPN uses openvpn as backend so if there were some custom openvpn client that did app-based split tunneling correctly, that would work. The current openvpn for windows doesn't seem able to.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I'm having the exact same issue